# ajax firing error function even the response is valid json and status 200

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am using windows server 2012 and i built web app it was working fine on my local PC

but when I uploaded the code to sever the **JQuery ajax** function firing error function?

I did search around to find out what is the problem but no thing help

I added `dataType:"text"` and it fire the **success function** but it does not deal with the returned data as JSON. while when I added `dataType:"json"` it kept firing the error function

```
    $.ajax({
    url:url,
    type:"POST",
    data:{collegeID: ID},

    success:function(res){
     if(res.success == 1){
       trigger.append("<OPTION value=''>--Select Teacher--</OPTION>");
       $.each(res.data,function(){
        trigger.append(
            "<OPTION VALUE='"+this.teacher_id+"'>"+this.teacher_name_e+" | "+this.teacher_name_a+"</OPTION>"
        );
       });
     }else{
       trigger.append("<OPTION></OPTION>");
     }
     console.log(res);
    },
    error:function(e){
     trigger.append("<OPTION></OPTION>");
     console.log(e);
    }
});
```

response without adding dataType or with add dataType:"json"

[image]

response when I add dataType:"text"

[image]

Comment: check with `if(res.success == '1'){` or `if(res.success === '1'){` and let us know

Comment: post your url here. the problem is there

Comment: Thanks for response. It does not work either

Comment: @AlivetoDie ``("1" == 1)`` is ``true``, so the problem might be somewhere else

Comment: I think it's a cross-domain problem. What's your url?

Comment: you will need login to access the page

Comment: please mention the error you are getting?

Comment: We just need the url you passed in your ajax parameter, to be sure it's a cross-domain call.

Comment: here is my web app [http://37.98.226.42](http://37.98.226.42) and all my pages and database on the same server

Comment: i add to images in the description @SagarArora

Comment: Can you post your request and response header (Chrome Dev tools > Network tab)

Comment: please guys help me

Comment: here is my request and response headers [http://37.98.226.42/test/2.png](http://37.98.226.42/test/2.png)

Comment: [http://37.98.226.42/upload.php](http://37.98.226.42/upload.php) this is my page when i have the error. it will send request when you change the college